# Why are austenitic stainless steels not ferromagnetic?

Tags: ferromagnetism

There has been a question about this from 2015 but I don't think it has been answered well enough and the question also wasn't specific so I'm hoping that this time around, someone will be able to give a more detailed explanation because I'm curious: Why are [austenitic steels](https://bortec.de/en/blog/2017/08/08/austenitic-steel/) (mostly) not *ferromagnetic*?

Is it because of their face-centered cubic crystal structure? And if so, why? I understand why and how ferritic stainless steels become magnetic, but why can't austenitic stainless steels do the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Inox Steel doesn't interact with magnets?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90400/)

Comment: Your question is as difficult to answer as the question of why "normal" bcc structure, $\alpha$-phase iron is ferromagnetic.

Comment: -1. Have you googled your title? #1 hit is https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/why-dont-magnets-work-on/